# Remove wptexturize from a shortcode?

Tags: shortcode, formatting

Is there a way to remove `wptexturize` only for a certain shortcode?

Comment: What is the shortcode in question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a clue in `wp-includes/formatting.php` in the function `wptexturize`:

```
$default_no_texturize_shortcodes = array('code');
...
$no_texturize_shortcodes = '(' . implode('|',
    apply_filters('no_texturize_shortcodes', $default_no_texturize_shortcodes) ) . ')';
```

Try using this filter to add a shortcode to the array:

```
function my_no_tex( $shortcodes ) {
    $shortcodes[] = 'someshortcode';
    return $shortcodes;
}
add_filter( 'no_texturize_shortcodes', 'my_no_tex' );
```

Answer (score 3):

Shortcodes run after the wptexturize function, so they shouldn't get processed by it anyway.

wptexturize runs on the_content with priority 10. The do_shortcode function runs with priority 11.